# How can I share my laptop WiFi with my Raspberry Pi via ethernet?

Tags: command-line, arch-linux, raspberry-pi, ethernet

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and I am trying to get WiFi working on it. I cannot seem to get the wireless to work in the command line so I would like to use my laptops WiFi instead. Both devices have an ethernet port. My laptop has Antergos (Arch Linux-based) and my Raspberry Pi has Arch Linux from their arm branch.

Answer (score 5):

This is fairly simple with some basic routing and NAT, using the laptop as a router. For simplicity's sake, `eth0` will be the Ethernet interface on both devices and `wlan0` will be your laptop's wireless interface. `192.168.2.0/24` will be the IP address range used between the laptop and Pi.

First, add a static IP address to the laptop's eth0:

```
ip addr add 192.168.2.1/24 dev eth0
```

And to the Pi:

```
ip addr add 192.168.2.2/24 dev eth0
ip route add default via 192.168.2.1
```

Enable IP forwarding on the laptop:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Enable NAT on the laptop:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Ensure there are no firewall rules in the iptables `FORWARD` chain on the laptop, else things may not work. Note that none of these settings will persist a reboot, and you may also need to set up DNS on the Pi to point to the correct address.

Comment: Does not Pi also need a default GW pointed at laptop's IP?

Comment: @ajeh it's included above right after the address is added

Comment: I just thought that turning Pi into a router is a kind of overkill.

Comment: @ajeh the Pi is not being turned into a router

Comment: I'm still not getting any signal. I tried ping 8.8.8.8 and it said that destination host is unavailable. I then tried to do pacman -Syyu and it timed out every time. Can I enable ipv6 forwarding too?